# I just CAN'T cut this product out in a professional manner

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background

I'm hoping you guys can help.  I've been using photoshop for donkeys years, but the one difficulty I have is cutting out products in a professional way.  I decided to take the underlying photo on a black background because the product is white.

I have attempted inverting the black, magic wand, AND quick selection tool but just can't get a nice result.  I know the quality of the image isn't great, but my DSLR is pretty old now.

Hope you guys can offer some advice.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQkyp.jpg

[image]

Comment: it could use better lighting. Lighting always helps with these things

Comment: We've got a few questions already for cutting images out: [**How do I trace an image and place it over a different background?**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/19692/8708) and [**Completely remove background from image**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/1147/8708). There are a few techniques in those posts. If they don't work, then feel free to post a new question with an example of what you've tried and why it's not quite what you're looking for. Good luck!

Comment: This is a snap to extract via channels. http://i.stack.imgur.com/2OtQ8.png

Comment: Hi Scott - how do I do this?

Comment: James, duplicate Blue channel and highlight it in Channel Panel. Levels adjust to make white white and black black. Brush to paint unwanted areas black and wanted areas white. Load as selection, apply as mask to layer.

Comment: Ouch, I just typed up a response and the post got closed as I was typing:) @JamesBriggs: the links above will walk you through it. Note that a mask is a greyscale image. What this means is that you can use multiple techniques to construct a greyscale image and then paste that into a layer mask.

Comment: For future photos, if you separate the backdrop from the product by several feet, you can light them separately. Use a white backdrop, and use four lights, 2 for the foreground 2 for background. Put up blinders for the background lights to prevent light from getting forward. Take 2 shots without moving the camera: 1 with foreground lights only, 1 with background lights only. If you set things up just right, you will have 1 shot with a lit product against a black background and 1 product of a white background with a silhouette of the product. The bg one can be used as a mask.

Comment: See for instance: http://www.zarias.com/white-seamless-tutorial-part-1-gear-space/

Answer (score 1):

I cheat with Quick Mask.

Make a rough selection using your method of choice.

Go into Quick Mask and (depending on your preference and settings) use either the eraser or pencil/brush to make your selection perfect. Flip out of Quick Mask and delete occasionally to check your work.